# Selection of rainfalls seasons for Sentintel-2 data in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, date

I want to filter the Sentinel ImageCollection for the rainseasons of my ROI (March to may AND October to December) for all data available (2015-2018).
With .filterDate(startdate, enddate) I can only filter one season of one year. With my code I get an Error: Layer 1: Layer error: User memory limit exceeded. Is there another way?

```js
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterDate('2016-03-01', '2016-05-31')
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(3,5,'month'))
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(10,12,'month'));

var composite = s2.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
              .map(maskS2clouds)
              .median();

function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  var cloudBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(10).int();
  var cirrusBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(11).int();
  var mask = 
  qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
  }

Map.setCenter(37.5211, 1.3182, 13);
Map.addLayer(composite, {bands: ['B3', 'B2', 'B1'], min: 0, max: 0.3});
```

Comment: You use `ee.Filter.calendarRange(3,5,'month')` and over this result, you apply `ee.Filter.calendarRange(10,12,'month')`. There is no 10-12 month after applying the first filter. Maybe this could be the root of your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, the problem is with a double filter without and `or` or `and` condition. Use:

```js
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterDate('2016-03-01', '2016-05-31')
.filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.calendarRange(3,5,'month'),
ee.Filter.calendarRange(10,12,'month')));

var composite = s2.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
              .map(maskS2clouds)
              .median();

function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  var cloudBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(10).int();
  var cirrusBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(11).int();
  var mask = 
  qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
  }

Map.setCenter(37.5211, 1.3182, 13);
Map.addLayer(composite, {bands: ['B3', 'B2', 'B1'], min: 0, max: 0.3});
```

Comment: Link to example: https://code.earthengine.google.com/218c34894402fcb77d711f97c07c4cf2

Comment: Thank you so much! 
It worked with the or condition, but not with the and condition. I dont know why. But it should not make a difference because the or condition is inclusive, right?
I also defined the region of interest so it doesn't run out of memory.

Comment: With `and` you need to agree with both conditions... You can't have an image of two different months. I put `and` and `or` as two ways to apply different filters at the same time, each use depends on the desired output. If this answer was helpful, please accept it (tick mark in up-left corner of the answer), this is how this site works